# How can I get the name of an Akka actor from within the actor itself?

Tags: scala, akka

So, if I have an actor, I can give it a name. But, can I access that name internally? Example:

```
class Actorz extends Actor with ActorLogging {
   val actorName = //??What function

   def receive = {
     case x => log.debug(actorName+": Received Message: "+x)
   }
}

val actor = system.actorOf(Props[Actorz], "named")
actor ! "dogs"
```

Now, I can pass its name as a constructor parameter. But, that seems like unnecessary duplication if there is a way to get the name internally... as it was set when I instantiated the actor using `system.actorOf`. API docs didn't seem to have anything.

Comment: Why do you need actor's `name` if you are using `ActorLogging`? Logger provides by default all required information about actor to detect one.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

From an `Actor` you can use `self` to get the `ActorRef`.

```
val actorName = self.path.name
```

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.Actor

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.ActorRef

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.ActorPath