# Obtaining ActorRef's Name

Tags: scala, akka

How is it possible to obtain the name of an ActorRef?

Suppose the following actor is declared:

`val a = system.actorOf(Props(new X(false)), name = "a")`

How the name("a") can be retrieved from an ActorRef of type`X`?

Comment: I believe you can get it from ActorPath

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887419/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-akka-actor-from-within-the-actor-itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActorPath.name has it:

```
a.path.name
```